# Unit Testing for ContentDocument processes

Tags: unit-test, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

Here is my testclass:

```
ContentVersion contentversion = TestDataFactory.createContentVersion('test', 'test', 'test');
                   
Set<Id> testSet = new Set<Id>();
testSet.add(contentversion.id);
                    
List<ContentDocumentLink> docLinks = [  
             SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId 
             FROM ContentDocumentLink 
             WHERE ContentDocument.Title = 'A'
              AND LinkedEntityId IN :testSet
                        ];
// check if file already exists, 
// if yes, insert a newer ContentVersion by specifying the ContentDocumentId
if (!docLinks.isEmpty()) {
    contentversion.ContentDocumentId = docLinks[0].ContentDocumentId;
}
insert(contentversion);
                    
                    
List<ContentVersion> contentVersionquery = [SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion];
                    
contentVersionquery.add(contentversion);
                    
update contentVersionquery;
```

And this is my error message:

*System.QueryException: Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.*

Why the error? I see I'm using a filter with IN on LinkedEntityId.

Comment: `LinkedEntityId` is the ID of the linked object. You are passing `ContentVersion` `ID` in `LinkedEntityId` filter which is not correct.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!